# Runtime Error When Executing Stored Procedure Inside SSIS Script Task

Tags: sql, sql-server, vbscript, ssis, etl

I'm getting a strange error when executing a stored procedure from an SSIS script task. Its strange because it only occurs with the stored procedure I need it to run. If I point to another stored procedure in the same database, then it runs without error. I'm doing this in a script task so I can capture PRINT messages from the procedure to the SSIS log for troubleshooting reasons.

Here is the code in the script task:

```
 Public Sub Main()
    Dim conn As New SqlConnection("server=MyServer;Integrated Security=SSPI;database=MyDatabase")
    AddHandler conn.InfoMessage, New SqlInfoMessageEventHandler(AddressOf OnInfoMessage)
    conn.Open()
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand()
    cmd.Connection = conn
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    cmd.CommandText = "[logtesting]"
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    conn.Close()
    Dts.TaskResult = ScriptResults.Success
End Sub
Private Sub OnInfoMessage(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal args As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInfoMessageEventArgs)
    Dim sqlEvent As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlError
    For Each sqlEvent In args.Errors
        Dts.Events.FireInformation(sqlEvent.Number, sqlEvent.Procedure, sqlEvent.Message, "", 0, False)
    Next
End Sub
```

32 bit Package built in VS2010, running against a SQL 2012 Server.

The failure is immediate and if I comment out

```
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

then it runs fine.

Error Message:

> at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
>       at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
>       at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
>       at System.RuntimeType.InvokeMember(String name, BindingFlags bindingFlags, Binder binder, Object target, Object[] providedArgs, ParameterModifier[] modifiers, CultureInfo culture, String[] namedParams)
>       at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTATaskScriptingEngine.ExecuteScript()

Comment: Have you considered wrapping the call in a try/catch to see if you can get more helpful error information? Also, does the SP `logtesting` actually exist in the database? Works when you run it manually?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I did that and found that the cmd was timing out. I set cmd.CommandTimeout=0 and its running now (fingers crossed). Thanks again!

Comment: I am waiting too... fingers crossed.... :)

Comment: @R.Richards even if it was a basic solution, you have to write it as an answer. so the question will be marked as answered :)

Comment: @neuralgroove Is this resolved?

Comment: Yes, this is resolved. Thanks for the advice..